# Mysql - selecting year from a unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp

I am using this:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y') AS year FROM table_name WHERE year = 2009;
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Unknown column 'year' in 'where clause'SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y') AS year FROM table_name WHERE year = 2009
```

Both "my_unix_timestamp_column" and "table_name" are correct, i dont know why it gives me this!!!

I'm using PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm not quite sure whether this is due to `YEAR` being a reserved word in MySQL or because it wants you to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y') AS year
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y') = 2009;
```

Can't remember whether the last issue is only relevant to `GROUP`ings :S

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y') AS `year`
FROM    table_name
HAVING  `year` = 2009
```

Unlike `WHERE` clause, `HAVING` clause can reference the `SELECT` clause aliases.

More index efficient way would be:

```
SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y') AS `year`
FROM    table_name
WHERE   my_unix_timestamp_column >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-01-01')
        AND my_unix_timestamp_column < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-01')
```

Comment: while both of these queries work, this answer doesn't describe why both solve the problem of `year` in the where clause. (also both are structured in a slightly less normal way than matching against the year in the where clause)

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative, avoiding repetition of a biggish function call:

```
SELECT year
  FROM (SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y') AS year
          FROM table_name) AS list_of_years
 WHERE year = 2009;
```

You might still need to use back-quotes around the word 'year' to avoid conflicts with YEAR as a keyword.  The optimizer should not need to create an intermediate table to answer this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a column created the `SELECT` section in your `WHERE` clause

replace the `year` variable in your where clause with the actual function to create that column (aka `FROM_UNIXTIME(my_unix_timestamp_column, '%Y')` ) and you should be fine.

This is because the `SELECT` section of your query isn't executed until the `WHERE` section has finished matching rows to return.

Comment: The part about `SELECT` section is just wrong. I won't downvote you, but try to run the following query: `SET @r := 1; SELECT @r := id + 1 FROM mytable WHERE @r = id` on any table with consecutive ids starting from `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE part is executed before the aliasing in the field list. Best thing is to use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) in the WHERE clause so an index can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but would this work?

```
SELECT YEAR(my_unix_timestamp_column) AS 'year'
FROM table_name
WHERE YEAR(my_unix_timestamp_column) = 2009;
```

Ref link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_year.asp