# Query MYSQL for events that occurred only in 2013

Tags: php, mysql, modx

I am trying to search my database and find results for venues that only occurred in a given year, like 2012, 2013, etc.

The catch: The 'venue date' is in UNIX time. And now I'm having issues figuring out how to format the search properly. Here is what I have, however the query is pulling all venues still.

```
$s = $modx->newQuery('Venues');
$s->where(array(strftime('%Y','Venues.venue_date') => '2012'));
$shops = $modx->getCollection('Venues',$s);
```

Any idea if what I am attempting to do is possible? Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the two answers, I was able to get on the correct track. I reviewed this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html which is essentially a goldmine for me :) And below is the simplified code...

`$s->where('Year(from_unixtime(Venues.venue_date))=2013');`

Thanks again, hopefully people find this useful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? `FROM_UNIXTIME('Venues.venue_date', '%Y')`

[Mysql - selecting year from a unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708953/mysql-selecting-year-from-a-unix-timestamp)

Comment: Thank you, this got me on the correct track. I will update my question to show the solution. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your other code, but for selecting a UNIX time, what about formatting the date to a unix timestamp by:

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2012)
```

So your second line would become:

```
$s->where(array(strftime('%Y','Venues.venue_date') => ''.mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2012).''));
```